# Refers simply to "Ubuntu" on the welcome bar

Tags: bug, status-completed

Clearly this should say "Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!" - it's the little things that matter...

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This has been updated but might take 24 hours to show up due to caching.